# The usage of an ampersand(&) in printf and format specifiers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char  a;
    printf("What? \t");

    scanf("%s", &a);

    printf("U have to %s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I build and run this code and enter a value in `%s`, I get an error and the debug program stops working and closes. But when I use ampersand sign like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char  a;
    printf("What? \t");

    scanf("%s", &a);

    printf("U have to %s", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

in the `printf`... it works. Why is that? It also differs between the format specifier, such as one doesn't need to put `&` (ampersand) sign in `printf` when one uses `%c` or `%d` in the `scanf`. Why does this happen and is it related to the data types and which format specifiers concludes this result?

(sorry for my bad English. I am not a native English speaker and this is my first time here).

Comment: `%s` requires a pointer to a string, not a single character.

Comment: Undefined behaviour isn't required to fail; it isn't required to work, either.  The behaviour is undefined and anything may happen.  Passing a pointer to a single character to `scanf()` with `%s` as the corresponding conversion specification is invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have here is a classic example of code that seems to work, but for the wrong reasons.

Let's review a few things about `printf` and `scanf`.  The format specifier `%d` is for values of type `int`.  You can read an integer like this:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
```

And you can print it back out like this:

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Why does one use an `&` and one does not?  Well, C uses what's called "pass by value".  If we wrote

```
scanf("%d", i);    /* WRONG */
```

we would be passing the value of `i` *to* `scanf`.  But we don't want to pass the (old) value of `i` to `scanf`, we want `scanf` to read a new value, and store it into `i`.  In other words, we want `scanf` to, in effect, pass the new value of `i` back to us. For that to work, we instead pass `scanf` a *pointer to* the variable `i` where we want it to store the just-read integer.  That's what the `&` does -- it generates a pointer to `i`.

When we call `printf`, on the other hand, the regular way of passing arguments works just fine.  We do want to pass `i`'s value to `printf` so that it can print it out.  If we were to call

```
printf("%d\n", &i);    /* WRONG */
```

it wouldn't work, because `printf` expects an `int`, and here we're wrongly handing it a pointer-to-`int`.

So now we've learned that for integers with `%d`, `printf` wants an `int` and `scanf` wants a pointer-to-`int`.

Let's talk about characters.  The format `%c` is for characters.  We can read one character with `scanf`:

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
```

And we can print it with `printf`:

```
printf("%c\n", c);
```

Again, the pattern is exactly the same.  `scanf` needs a pointer, so that it can fill in the value, so we pass `&c`.  But `printf` just needs the value, so we pass plain `c`.

Now we get to strings.  A string in C is an *array of characters*.  Also strings in C are always terminated by a special null character, `'\0'`, that marks the end of the string.  So if we wanted to declare a variable that could contain strings up to 9 characters long, we might write

```
char s[10];
```

That gives us room for 9 characters, plus the terminating `'\0'`.

But arrays are special in C: Whenever you pass an array to a function, or whenever you do anything that would require the "value" of the array, what you get instead (what the compiler automatically generates for you) is a pointer to the array's first element.

What this means is that to read a string with `scanf` and `%s`, we can just call:

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

"But where is the `&`?", you ask.  "I thought you always needed an `&` when calling `scanf`!"

Well, not quite.  You always need a *pointer* when calling `scanf`.  And in fact, when you called `scanf("%s", s)`, it was just as if you had written

```
scanf("%s", &s[0]);
```

When you use `%s` with `scanf`, it expects a pointer to the first of several characters, that is, a pointer to the beginning of an array of characters, where it should begin writing the string it reads.  (How does it know how big the array is?  What if the user types a string that's too long to fit in the array?  We'll get to those points in a moment.)

You can print strings with `%s` too, of course, and it looks like this:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

This is, again, just as if you had written

```
printf("%s\n", &s[0]);
```

When you use `%s` with `printf`, it expects a pointer to the first of several characters which it should begin printing, until it finds the terminating `'\0'` character.

So `%s` is special with `printf` and `scanf`, because strings are special (because arrays are special).  With `%d` and `%c` and just about every other format specifier, you usually need a `&` when you call `scanf`, and you usually don't want that `&` when you call `printf`.  But with `%s`, you usually don't want the `&` for either `printf` or `scanf`.

(And if we think about it a bit more carefully, the exception is not so much that `scanf` and `%s` does not need the `&`.  Remember, the rule is really, `scanf` always needs pointers.  The only reason `scanf` and `%s` doesn't need an `&` is that when you pass an array, you get a pointer to the array's first element automatically.  So the exception is really for `printf` and `%s`: `printf` and `%s` *does* expect a pointer, and the reason `printf` and `%s` is designed to expect a pointer is that there's no way to not give it one: it *has* to accept a pointer, because for strings, that's what you always end up giving it.)

So the rule with `%s` is that `scanf` expects a pointer to the first of several characters, and `printf` expects a pointer to the first of several characters, too.

So now, with all that background out of the way, we can look at your code.  You basically wrote

```
char c;
scanf("%s", &c);
```

At first this might seem to be kinda, sorta, almost correct.  `scanf` and `%s` wants a pointer to a character, and you gave it `&c`, which is a pointer to a character.  But `%s` really wants a pointer *to the first of several characters*.  But you gave it a pointer to just a single character.  So when the user types a string, the first character typed will get stored in `c`, but the rest of the characters, and the terminating `'\0'`, will get written to unallocated memory somewhere off to the right of variable `c`.  They'll overwrite ("clobber") memory that was, perhaps, used for something else.  This is a serious problem, but it might not become evident right away.

Finally, you tried to print things out again with `printf`.  You first tried

```
printf("%s\n", c);    /* WRONG */
```

but this didn't work at all.  The reason is that `%s` with `printf` expects a pointer-to-`char`, but you gave it a plain `char`.  Suppose `c` contains the letter `'A'`.  This would end up asking `printf` to go to address 65 and begin printing characters until it finds the terminating `'\0'`.  Why address 65?  Because 65 is the ASCII code for `A`.  But there's probably not a proper, null-terminated string starting at address 65 in memory; in fact there's a good chance your program doesn't have permission to read from address 65 at all.

So then you tried

```
printf("%s\n", &c);    /* ALSO WRONG */
```

and this *seemed* to work.  It "worked" because, *if* scanf succeeded in storing a complete string into `c` and the unallocated memory off to the right of it, and if clobbering that memory somehow didn't cause (too many) other problems, then when you pass the pointer `&c` to `printf`, printf can find those characters, making up a string, and print them out.

So it "works", but as I said, for the wrong reasons: in the process it stomps all over memory it doesn't "own", and sooner or later, something else is going to not work as a result.

How should you have scanned and printed a string?  One way is like this, as we saw before:

```
char s[10];
scanf("%s", s);

printf("%s\n", s);
```

Now when `scanf` gets a pointer to the first element of the array `s`, it has 10 characters to play with.

We really do have to worry about the possibility that the user will type more than 9 characters.  But there's a fix for that: we can tell `scanf` how long a string it's allowed to read, how many characters it's allowed to write to the array we handed it:

```
scanf("%9s", s);
```

That `9` in there tells `scanf` that it's not allowed to read more than 9 characters from the user.  And since 9 is less than 10, there's still room for the terminating `'\0'` character.

There's much more that could be said about `scanf`.  As chqrlie noted in a comment, it's important to check its return value, to make sure it succeeded in converting as many values as you wanted it to.  It's got some strange rules about whitespace.  Unless you know what you're doing, you can't intermix calls to `scanf` with calls to other input-reading functions like `getchar` or `fgets` -- you'll get strange results.  And, finally, scanf is so persnickety and (in the end) so lacking in truly useful functionality that it's not really worth using at all.  But those are topics for another day, since this answer is [tl;dr](http://catplanet.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/tldr.jpg) already.

Comment: Quite an extensive course about `scanf()`... but you might want to also teach the user about the return value and the need to test it.

Comment: @chqrlie Good point.  The answer is too long already, but that's worth mentioning.

Comment: great answer!  I think it's also worth explicitly saying something brief about *undefined behavior* : right about where this answer says "this seemed to work", I would hasten to add that a program triggering undefined behavior might very well (seem to) work in one context and then not work in another context *even when the program itself is exactly the same*; so you could even have a program that "works" in your debugger and in your IDE, but then behaves radically differently running on the command line; new programmers need to learn this well, and learn it early

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier requires a pointer to a string. When used with `scanf`, it must be a `char` array with enough characters for the word you enter plus the trailing null byte that indicates the end of the string. In `printf()` it has to be a null-terminated `char` array.

Using a pointer to a `char` variable doesn't work, because it doesn't have room for the null byte. You're causing undefined behavior by writing outside the variable.

```
char word[100];
scanf("%s", word);
printf("%s\n", word);
```

You can use `%c` to read and write a single character rather than a string of multiple characters.

```
char letter;
scanf("%c", &letter);
printf("%c\n", letter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In statement `char  a;` `a` is a character variable & to scan a char variable  use `%c` format specifier.

```
scanf("%s",a);/* %s expects base address of char buffer, not single char */
scanf(" %c",&a);/* this is correct */
```

If you want to scan using `%s` then your input should be char buffer like `char buf[10]`. for e.g

```
char a[10];
scanf("%s",a);
```

*u don't need to put &(ampersand) sign in printf when u use %c or %d ?* no need to provide address `&` to `printf()` as `printf()` job is to print not to scan. for e.g

```
char input;
scanf("%c",&input);/* here you need &, As scanf() will store input char into
                      address you provided i.e &input */
printf("%c",input);/*here no need &input, bcz input char already stored,
                     printf will just print the char*/
```

Well, if you print the address you can use `%p`.

```
printf("%p",a);/*a is char buffer */
```