# why a pointer in C can print his content without dereference?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I created a program in which I noticed two things

1. I used the address of pointer to print the whole word and It works but when I replaced s with
   *s it did not work (why is this happened?) (I used address in printf not *s the content)
2. When I used pointer to pointer to print the character I could not print anything (I mean when
   I replaced %s with %c

My code :

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    char str[10]="PinkFloyd";
    char *s;
    char **s1;
    
     s=&str[0];
     
     s1=&s;
     
     printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %s",*s1); //why if I used %c does not print the first character 
     printf("\n");
     printf("the word is using s pointer %s",s); // why if I had replaced with *s does not print anything
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*s` has the type `char` - so, you could use `printf("%c", *s);` to print that _one_ `char` that `s` is pointing at.

Comment: You need to look into the manual for `printf`. The correct type of parameter depends on the format specifier. For `%s` it is `printf` doing the dereferencing for you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok but why when I used the address it prints the whole word? 
I expect to have an udefined behavior but it works

Comment: Because `%s` prints one char at a time by doing something like `while(*s != '\0') { putchar(*s); ++s; }` (where `s` is the `char*` you supplied to `printf`)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `*` to print a string because, in effect, `printf` does it for you.

When you use `%s` with `printf`, it turns out you do not actually pass your string to `printf`.  You pass a pointer to the string's first character, and `printf` takes care of stepping along the string and printing all its characters.

This is no different, though, from the way strings are handled everywhere in C.  Strings are arrays, but arrays are "second class citizens" in C, which basically means you never pass them around in their entirety.  Pretty much every library function in C that works with strings, works with them by using pointers to their first characters.

If you call

```
printf("%s", *s);      /* WRONG */
```

it doesn't work.  `*s` gives you the contents of the pointed-to pointer, which is the character `'P'`.  But `%s` wants a pointer, not a character.

You might also find [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074855) interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier, prints a null terminated string pointed to by the parameter. That means that it starts from the address in the parameter, and prints one character at  a time until it reaches a `0` (not the character but the actual numeric value 0).

In your case, `s1` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` the first character of the string, so the dereferenced `*s1` is a pointer to a null terminated string. The variable `s` is a pointer to a `char`, so the dereferenced `*s` is a character.

If you used the format specifier for printing a null terminated string (`%s`) and passed a regular character, you would pass a numeric value (all characters are numerical value) to the `printf` method and it would try to read it, as if it was a memory address where it should read the string from. `%c` on the other hand expects the number to be a single character, and not a memory address.

If you want to print the first character (`%c`) then for `s1` you would have to use `**s1` and for `s` you would have to use `*s`. If you want to print the entire string (`%s`), then you would have to point to the first character of the string you want to print, so for `s1` that would `*s1` and for `s` you would have to use `s` (it is already a pointer to `char`).

```
// Print the entire string
const char *s = "Some String";
printf("%s", s);
// Prints:
// Some String

// Move the pointer and start inside the string
printf("%s", s + 5);
// Prints:
// String

// Print a single character
printf("%c", *s);
// Prints:
// S

// Create a pointer to a pointer to s
const char **ps = &s;
printf("%s", *ps);
// Prints:
// Some String

// Print the first character
printf("%c", **ps);
// Prints:
// S
```

In the above example `s == *ps` so when you dereference a point to a pointer to *something* you end up with a pointer to *something*. You can read more about the different format specifiers for the `printf`-like functions here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters

Comment: `" *s1 is a pointer to a null terminated string"` 
So when I use a pointer to pointer this points to the whole string so when  I dereference I will take the whole string and when I decay a pointer to a string  and I dereference it I wll print the first character?

Comment: @vgag1997 when you create a pointer to a pointer, that pointer points to the second pointer. When you dereference the pointer, you are left with the other pointer. That pointer points to the first character of the string.

Comment: @ Tommy Andersen 
[link] (https://imgur.com/a/iP5CS97)  This is how I think this but if this happened how `s1` will store the whole word? because the s1 points to s which points to the first character not in the whole word this is the point that I confused Excuse me if i insist

Comment: You are correct, but `s1` does not store the whole word, it only stores the memory of address of `s` and `s` stores the memory address of the first character, not the whole word.

Answer (score 1):

> Why if I used `%c` does not print the first character?
>
> ```
> printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %s", *s1);
> ```

`%c` expects to find an `int` (representing a `char`) where your `*s1` argument is. That `int` holds the `unsigned char` value of the character (after conversion) that `printf("%c",...)` would print. `*s1` is a `char*` and holds an address - possibly wider (`sizeof(char*)`) than an `int` (`sizeof(int)`) and `printf` may therefore leave values on the stack and then you have *Undefined behavior*.

> Why if I had replaced with `*s` does not print anything?
>
> ```
> printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %s", *s1);
> ```

Here you have a similar situation. `%s` expects a `char*` where you have `*s1`. It will use that `char*` to dereference the pointer and move it forward until it finds a `'\0'` character:

```
for(; *s1 != '\0'; ++s1) putchar(*s1);
```

By supplying `*s` instead, you supply the `char` value at the address pointed at by `s`. That's usually a value in the range `[-128, 127]` and is very unlikely a valid address. `printf` will nevertheless pick a `char*` value from the stack (possibly messing the stack up because it picks too many bytes) and beginnig the loop above, reading from the wrong memory addresses. Again *Undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[10]="PinkFloyd";
    char *s;
    char **s1;
    
     s=&str[0];
     
     s1=&s;
     
     printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c",*s1[0]); //why if I used %c does not print the first character 
     printf("\n");
     printf("the word is using s pointer %s",s); // why if I had replaced with *s does not print anything
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion specifier `%s` of the function `printf` expects an argument of the type `char *` that points to first character of a string. In such a case the function outputs all characters of the string until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered. For example

```
printf("the word is using s pointer %s",s);
```

If you will write

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %s",*s);
```

then the expression `*s` has the type `char` instead of the type `char *`. So this call is incorrect. The function will try to interpret the internal representation of the character `'P'` as a pointer of the type `char *`

Instead you could write

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c",*s);
```

using the conversion specifier `%c`. In this case the pointed single character will be outputted.

A similar problem exists with this call

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c",*s1);
```

the expression `*s1` has the type `char *` but the conversion specifier `%c` expects an object of the type `char`.

So you need to supply an object of the type `char` as for example

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c", **s1);
```

or

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c",( *s1 )[0] );
```

or

```
printf("the word is using pointer to pointer %c",s1[0][0] );
```

Comment: Aside: "conversion specifier %c expects an object of the type char." --> of type `int`.  "the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and
the resulting character is written."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It expects an argument of the type char. But due to integer conversions the argument is converted to the type int and in turn is converted to unsigned char by the function  and is outputted.