# Just want to know how this code written in C works

Tags: c, pointers, input, output, ampersand

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *name;
    printf("Enter a name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
    printf("%s", &name);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I created a dangling pointer i.e. doesn't point to any adress and I tried storing a string into it and i found that using an ampersand before pointer worked for I-O but i just don't know why. I'm just getting started with C.

Here is how the output looks

```
Enter a name: Joseph Tribbiani
Joseph Tribbiani
```

Comment: note - although the data types are different, the underlying issue is the same as the duplicate (writing outside bounds of allocated memory)

Comment: If you had written `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` it would have been quite a bit more more likely to crash.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074855/the-usage-of-an-ampersand-in-printf-and-format-specifiers/50075252#50075252).

Comment: what's with all these phantom `s` after the `[` specifier? (in the question and answers and comments)

Comment: There's also undefined behaviour due to incorrect argument type for `scanf` and `printf`

Comment: @M.M Good catch.  They are just one more indicator that nobody should try to use `%[...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the ampersand `&name`, you are actually taking the address of the variable `name`, which is a pointer to char. Yes, `name` doesn't point to any adress, but it's still a variable and it takes up space to store its value, just like an `int` variable. Depending on your architecture, `name` takes up 4 or 8 bytes. This means you can store bytes into this `name` variable just you would any other variable.

Your code works because you are **using the variable `name` as a char array to store your input**. You `scanf` the string and store it to `name` and then `printf` it out. You can either input 4 or 8 one-byte chars before using up `name`'s size. (UPD: Thanks Andy in the comment, since `scanf` adds a null termination byte, it's actually 3 or 7 chars. I totally forgot about that :p)

On my 64bit Ubuntu 20.10 with gcc 10.3.0, I got [stack smashing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected) if I input more than 8 chars. However, if I input `abcdefgh` and print out the value of `name` (not `&name`) using `printf("%p", name)`, I will get `0x6867666564636261`. Recall that the ASCII code for the character `a` is 97, aka 0x61. And since my pc uses [Little Endian Byte Order](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html), the least significant byte of `0x6867666564636261` is just `0x61`. This means `'a'` is stored at the first byte of `name`, and `'b'`, `'c'` ... follows, just like a char array.

Comment: Don't forget scanf adds a null termination byte - so really it's 3 or 7 one-byte chars.  Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `&name` is indicating "use the address of the pointer variable 'name'" as the destination of the scanf.

The `scanf` is using the pointer variable address (an allocation of 4 or 8 bytes depending on architecture) and corrupting the stack (provided more than 3 or 7 characters are entered) - which has no effect in a simple main program.  (Why more than 3 or 7? Because `scanf` adds a null-terminator.)

A compiler warning is likely displayed as in:

```
main.c:20:14: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
```

This program shows the corruption:

```
int main()
{
    char s[20] = "Hello World\n";  // the storage for 's' is corrupted by the scanf
    char *name;

    printf("%s",s);    
    printf("Enter a name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
    printf("%s\n", &name);
    printf("%s",s);    
}
```

Produces:

```
Hello World
Enter a name: its a small world
its a small world
all world
```